# Soap connection to magento deployed on AWS Elastic Load Balancer

Tags: magento, soap, amazon-web-services

I am having a magento store deployed on Elastic load balancer provided by Amazon Web Services. I have 2 instances setup behind ELB. I upload products from external environment using magento's Soap API. Before setting up the ELB, it was working fine, but now its showing the following error

Error: Fatal Error (1): SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://www.mysite.com/api/soap/?wsdl' : failed to load external entity "http://www.mysite.com/api/soap/?wsdl"

Problem with connection is that its not consistent, it connects sometimes and sometimes not.
I think its because of the ELB.
Any help would be welcome..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a problem with the section, you have to enabled Stickiness in the ELB

Thanks